# Will my floating shelf hold a fish tank weighing approx 33kg?

Tags: walls, shelving

I have a 60cm X 23cm floating shelf with 6 X 4mm x 50mm screws with rawl plugs. The shelf is rated at holding 25kg. I also installed 4 L-shaped brackets underneath, each with 3 X 4mm X 50mm screws and rawl plugs. Each of these brackets are rated at holding 20kg.

The shelf is on a brick wall, with a 20kg fish tank on it now, but I'm thinking of upgrading the fish tank to a tank that would probably be weighing double this. Would this be strong enough or would it be best to strengthen some more?

Comment: So then the shelf isn't really floating anymore?  It's attached with its internal anchors _and_ it has two L brackets under it?  What is the size of the shelf and the L brackets?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the shelf?

Comment: Is it a full brick wall or a veneer brick?

Answer (score 1):

Probably. 4 brackets rated at 20kg should, in theory, carry 80kg, loaded uniformly. This depends entirely on the integrity of the fasteners and the wall, of course. The original rating of the shelf as a floating assembly isn't particularly relevant.

I'd set it up, then do a test with progressively heavier dead (non-fishy) weight. It should be apparent if it's dramatically overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

No.  33kg is more than 25kg.  Doing this is dependent on how much you like the fish.